# MVVMLight and disabling/enabling button

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I have a recyclerview displaying views of items that have a switch and a button. When toggling the switch of an item, I need to enable or disable the button of that view. How can I do this using MVVMLight and Xamarin.Android? Could I get some example code? I have the swith.checked bound to a RelayCommand in my ViewModel.

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Please consider reading [ask] on how to write a good question. As you see, as is, it is getting downvoted and even close voted. 
Reasons may include: - Asking for tutorials / examples is off-topic and if needed, examples will be included in answers anyway. - If ever possible include an [mcve] or at least your best attempt that "did not work".

Answer (score 1):

Suppose following ViewModel:

```
private bool _switch = true;

// Bind switch.IsChecked to this property:
public bool Switch 
{
    get => _switch; 
    set => Set( nameof(Switch), ref _switch, value); 
}

private RelayCommand _btnCmd;
public RelayCommand ButtonCommand => _btnCmd ?? (_btnCmd = 
                        new RelayCommand(ButtonCommand_Execute, ButtonCommand_CanExecute));

// What will happen on Button Click    
private void ButtonCommand_Execute(){ /* ...*/ }

// Sets the Enabled Property of the Button according to the state of the Switch property.
private bool ButtonCommand_CanExecute() { return Switch; }
```

That should do the trick.
In situations where you need to explicitly notify about the change of the CanExecute value, you can call `ButtonCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`.

That's how I do it in WPF; I do not know if there are some specialities in conjunction with Xamarin, though.